# getting JavaScript client side divs to spawn inside of a parent div container

Tags: javascript, html, dom

so i've written some JS code that creates new div's every few milliseconds and stacks them up. but I want this script to happen inside the space of a DIV. so far the script runs outside of any div container.
is document.getElementById("parent-div").innerHTML=scriptFunction(); the right solution?

```
<script>
//where to begin. 
//wrap code in functions and load them up via an DOM event handler. 
//aim is too eliminate the function when the array collects 30 elements/data types. 


var collect = []; //this array has global scope. because it's..
//been declared using var outside of a function. 

window.onload = function(){

var holder = function(){


var invent = function(){

//var create = document.createElement("div").setAttribute("id","posts");

var d = document.createElement("div"); 
  d.style.width="350px"; 
  d.style.height="100px"; 
  d.style.border="1px solid #333"; 
  d.style.cssFloat="left"; 
var random = Math.random();    

   i = 1; 
collect.push(i); 
var content = ["Bogus",
"<p>lala haha</p>", "<p>sooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</p>", "<P> foxy lady sinks into the bed</P>" ]; 
  d.innerHTML = collect.length + content[collect.length]; 
document.body.appendChild(d); //appendChild?


if(collect.length == 5){

alert("ahhhh 30"); //could trigger a new function. 

}

}; //end of invent. 

setInterval(invent,200); 




}; //end of holder function. 


//ok now i want this script to happen inside the "roll-out" div so i've tried this:
document.getElementById("roll-out").innerHTML=holder(); 

};
</script>
```

Comment: Are you trying to append the divs inside the parent div?

Comment: I think so yeah. but my problem is the program runs outside of the div i want it to be contained in.

Comment: What do mean by the program runs outside of it? JavaScript functions don't run within any particular DOM element. Most likely instead of appending to the body you want to append to the div instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
document.body.appendChild(d); //appendChild?
```

to something like

```
document.getElementById("parent-div").appendChild(d);
```

Comment: sure , i'll run it in the browser now. brb

Comment: Ok i seem to be getting somewhere now. I think that's done the trick. the JS client side divs are being spawned inside the pre-made parent div now, thanks.

Comment: my code is alittle sloppy though, so will have to wash it up abit. and figure out a way to kill the function (i gather using return; ) once enough of the new divs have been spawned :)

Comment: Return should work fine for breaking out of a function - if you store the value returned by `setInterval` you can use `clearInterval` to stop it from firing.

You should probably just use a loop though.

Comment: ahh niceone! still finding my way in the JS universe. walking around blind folded and getting a feel and concept for the language step by step.